# How to stop my chrome extension after opening it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently developing a chrome extension, that contains background.js and content_scripts.js. In content_scripts, I've added some "event.preventDefault"
 in all elements and also added some elements on the page. But when user clicks my extension for the second time, I'd like to "close" my extension and cancel all changes my extensions have done.

Is there a easy way to do that or do I have to treat all changes that I've made individually?

Comment: For the example you've given I'd just declare a global flag (`_active = true` for example) and only execute code when it's true.  When you execute the extension the 2nd time just toggle it to false.

Comment: It would prevent my extension from running twice, but it wouldn't undone all things the extension has done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, without reloading the page, there is no easy way to generically undo all your changes. Yes, if you want all your changes undone, then you have to undo them yourself. There is no magic recording being made of your changes which will back them out for you if your extension is disabled, or you call a particular API.

There are some obvious strategies for doing so:

- Remember the changes you made and undo them one by one (undo changes, remove event listeners, etc). What is required depends on what your extension did and the state you desire to leave it in. You can easily send a message to your content script with [`chrome.tabs.sendMessage()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage) which indicates that it should disable itself and/or back out any changes.
- Reload the page
- Store the initial state of at least portions of the page and restore it. This may difficult to do, and could be impossible on generic pages. You would have to know all of the event listeners and potentially other state information which has been set by JavaScript in the page.

Comment: That's what I thought so. Problem is I add some prevent defaults, so I guess the best way to achieve it is reloading the page. Thanks for your help; I will accept it as the best answer.

Comment: @LucasMello, Preventing defaults sounds like you are adding event listeners with [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). You can just remove the listeners with [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener). I do this in multiple extensions to disable the effects of the extension.

Comment: @LucasMello, it is relatively easy to keep a record of all the event listeners which you add and remove them when you need to disable the extension/content script. I do this in multiple situations where the listeners are applied dynamically (i.e. element, event type, etc are unknown when the code is written).

Comment: Of course! I'm removing all event listeners I've added and I don't need to reload the page! I didn't think in removing the listeners (I'm pretty new to javascript). Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
if(localStorage.getItem('firstClick')==='true'){
    localStorage.setItem('firstClick', 'false');
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "contentscript.js"});
}

else {
    localStorage.removeItem('firstClick');
    localStorage.set('firstClick', 'true')
}
```

Comment: this does not answer the question.